# *Some* members of pointer array not initialized to null?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

```
struct findaddress {
     struct findaddress *next[11];
     struct user *myuser;
};
int main(void){
struct findaddress *findhead=(struct findaddress *)(malloc(sizeof(struct findaddress)));
    int i=0;
    for (i;i!=11;i++){
        if (findhead->next[i]==NULL)puts("success");else puts("fail");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Result, disturbingly enough for me, is:

```
fail
fail
success
success
success
success
success
success
success
success
success
```

I have *no* idea why the two pointers on the bottom are failing, while the other pointers are passing.

Could someone be so kind as to enlighten me?

Comment: Did you expect calloc in place of malloc? Is it a typo ?

Comment: what's the definition of `struct findaddress`?

Comment: Since you've not set the data returned by `malloc()` to any known value, you get whatever garbage you get, and your code is at fault for trying to read the data before it is initialized.  It also seems odd to allocate one structure and then expect 11 of them to be available for checking...you've got some gaps in your code or your understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the definition, thought I had it on there.

Answer (score 5):

`malloc()` does not initialize the memory, only allocating the space on the heap. The content of the array you see is random. It is just the previous content of the same area.

Use `calloc()` if you want to make sure it is initialized with zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Why did you expect anything to be initialized to anything in this case? `malloc` does not initialize the allocated memory at all, which is basically what you are observing in your experiment.

If you want to zero-initialize your struct object, do

```
*findhead = (struct findaddress) { 0 };
```

after `malloc`. Or, if you want your memory to be filled with physical all-bits-zero pattern, use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

P.S. What is the purpose of that `i` in the first part of `for (i;i!=11;i++)`? If your `i` is already pre-initialized, you can just do `for (;i!=11;i++)`.

Comment: Does { 0 } have a meaning unique to structs, or a more general definition in the C language?

Comment: The `{ 0 }` initializer can be used with structures or arrays, and means 'initialize the first member (element) to zero, and implicitly initialize all the others to zero too'.  You can initialize the first element to any value you like (zero happened to be used in the example).  You can also initialize explicitly more members or elements than just the first by listing them.  See also 'designated initializers' in C99 and above.

Comment: @user1833028: In C the `{ 0 }` initializer can be used to *initialize* anything. Specifically in order to extend its applicability the language allows it even with scalars, e.g. `int x = { 0 }` is valid initialization. When it comes to *assignment*, you can use `{ 0 }` through compound literals (as shown in my answer) with anything except arrays (since arrays are not assignable).